# I am not able to clear_text in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

This is the link ->https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert

I need to remove the texts which I have mentioned in that image 
[image: not able to remove the texts using selenium]

I have used this path for locating the area

```
By.id("textareaCode");
```

but not able to delete. If I perform these action it was showing INVALIDEXCEPTIONSTATE.

Could please someone help me to remove the texts using selenium webdriver.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("textareaCode"));
element.Clear();
```

Please remember that you need to wait for page to load. I hope it'll help you :)